# Am I doing this Fancybox loading animation wrong?

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I am trying to get a fancybox loading animation to appear when an ajax request is made:

```
$(function() {
        $("html").ajaxStart(function() {
            $.fancybox.showActivity();
        });
        $("html").ajaxComplete(function() {
        $.fancybox.hideActivity();
        });
    });
```

Clicking on any button which makes an ajax request does nothing. I have the jquery, fancybox.js and fancybox css files linked to in the header.

Unless there is an obvious mistake I am making in the above, perhaps jqtouch is interferring with fancbox as I am also using that extensively as this is for a mobile website. I am testing in firefox.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The ajax functions should be targeting the element that has content being loaded into it not `html`

```
$("#content")
  .ajaxStart(function() {
    $.fancybox.showActivity();
  })
  .ajaxComplete(function() {
    $.fancybox.hideActivity();
  });
```

Comment: Attaching to the html is necessary for the ajaxStart and Complete functions to operate correctly within the jqtouch framework on the iphone. Attaching the functions to the relevant div did not work on the iphone, basically.